# Issue with BizTalk orchestration, generate no error but doesn't do anything

Tags: biztalk

I have BizTalk orchestration where it receives file and send file. I have expression shape calling .net class (method) to read xml file and upload file to SharePoint.  My expression shape has the following:

```
 XmlReader.readXml();
```

It's not passing any parameter nor return any value.
My Xml file gets send to send location and generate no error on window logs. However, it's not uploading file to sharepoint.  If I run XmlRead.readXml() by itself, I don't have any problem uploading to sharepoint.  How do I know if my .net is calling the method and executing?

Comment: Did you try this stuff yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233838/i-am-using-biztalk-orchestration-to-call-net-class-library-to-read-xml-when-ther

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233838

Answer (score 0):

OK, first thing. If there are no errors in the applications event log and BizTalk does not suspend throwing an exception then you know that your orchestration is working.

The fact that you are not getting the required behavior from it is not down to any biztalk weirdness.

Can you post the code from your expression shape and then it may be easier to find out what your problem is?

I am a little confused by your post because you say you are calling a .net class from an expression shape, but then you have a call to `XmlReader` in your expression shape. Is `XmlReader` your own class? If so then you do not seem to be passing any data into your `readXml()`. This may be why your call does nothing. If you need to pass a biztalk message into a method call from an orchestration you need to use the `XLANGMessage` type which can be found in the `MicroSoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes` assembly.

Hope this helps.